# php при нахождении строки в тексте изменять ее цвет

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

подскажите как при нахождении строки в тексте изменять ее цвет.
Если пользователь вводит в input просто слово которое нужно найти, цвет найденных слов меняется.
Но как сделать что бы если пользователь вводит через пробел 2 слова у них по отдельности менялся цвет. Если же пользователь вводит слова в кавычках то ищется словосочетание из нескольких слов и у них изменяется цвет.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        b{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Найти строку в тексте</h1>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <p>Ключевая строка: </p> 
        <input name="str" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
        <p name="text" class="text">
        <?php 
            require_once "search.php";
        ?></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php



$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut a voluptas quam, adipisci cum veritatis tenetur debitis et vero accusantium minus id quia, libero ipsam obcaecati maxime ipsa cupiditate harum modi doloribus? Voluptatem dignissimos quaerat, enim exercitationem nulla voluptatum mollitia qui facere porro velit illum blanditiis delectus fugiat iure, voluptates doloribus nesciunt aut. Facilis repudiandae maiores accusantium nemo sed rem aspernatur, minima dolorem tenetur quis facere ipsum optio porro praesentium repellat. Doloribus, tempora veritatis natus ea explicabo fugiat voluptatem nihil, assumenda numquam aperiam dolore, nesciunt corrupti sit est at quia illo ex. Debitis illum reprehenderit, molestias, maiores accusantium possimus unde pariatur praesentium autem suscipit, ducimus expedita est architecto ad deleniti. Explicabo earum reiciendis, labore eius temporibus inventore quisquam minima ab facilis? Velit amet atque et qui sapiente iusto voluptates porro rem mollitia reiciendis animi unde ipsa incidunt alias quos, sit nemo debitis odit omnis. Eum mollitia vero doloribus eaque, cupiditate sequi esse magni nulla ex, soluta, quos aut! Nisi ullam voluptatem beatae necessitatibus, perspiciatis ducimus architecto quae corporis ad neque ipsum modi voluptatibus quo itaque libero dolorem pariatur ipsam tenetur doloribus minus fuga enim, adipisci eveniet explicabo. Aut repellat eveniet at. Temporibus sed ab sint, quia quibusdam laboriosam. Sequi, eaque.";

$str = $_POST["str"];

// $regex = "/($str)/";

$regex = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);

echo str_replace($regex, '<b>'.$str.'</b>' ,$text);


// echo preg_replace("/$str/", $str, '<b>'.$str.'</b>');



echo $text;
```

Comment: допускается ли фраза вида `lorem "lorem ipsum"` то есть и кавычки и простое слово вместе? более того, надо учиывать, что отдельное слово, потенциально может входить в словосочетание. Или являться в тексте частью другого слова. В общем говоря, задача, далеко не трививальная

Comment: да такая фраза допускается

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос в заголовке:

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

$str = 'ipsum';

$colored = str_replace($str, '<b style="color: red">' . $str . '</b>' , $text);

echo $colored;
```

Если же нужно искать по нескольким словам, то строку поиска можно разбить на массив, и в цикле искать вхождения.

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

$str = 'ipsum dolor';

$colors = ['red', 'green'];

$exploded = explode(' ', $str);

foreach($exploded as $key => $word){
    $text = str_replace(trim($word), '<b style="color: ' . $colors[$key] . '">' . $word . '</b>' , $text);
}

echo $text;
```

Comment: вроде смысл вопроса был довольно очевидный. Спрашивали о том, как обработать словосочетания в кавычках, и отдельные слова. Надо полагать, что автор и так умеет пользоваться функцией замены.

Comment: Да, это я видел, но для людей которые найдут этот вопрос по заголовку, явно будет полезен этот ответ.

Comment: `if(preg_match_all("/(\w+)/", $str)){
    $str = trim($str,'"');
    str_replace($str, '<b>'.$str.'</b>', $text);
    $text = str_replace($str,'<b>'.$str .'</b>' , $text);
}`

Comment: если ввести 1 слово то работает, если отдельно ввести строку например "Lorem ipsum " тоже работает , но если ввести 2 слова через пробел выделяет их как единую а не ищет все совпадающие слова , и если ввести слово и потом в кавычках строку например Lorem "Debitis illum reprehenderit" то ничего не выделяет